# How to force redraw of a widget after changing some of its attributes?

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

Inside the call-back associated with a  `matplotlib.widgets.Slider` instance, I want to modify the Slider `valmin`, `valmax` and `val` attributes, and then re-draw the `Slider`. When I try to re-draw it, nothing happens.

Before the call-back completes, I call `plt.draw()` and, while the rest of the plot is correctly updated, the `Slider` looks the same as before. I also tried calling `draw()` on the `Axes` of the `Slider`, and again no visible change.

How can I force a re-draw of the `Slider` instance after changing its attributes?

Thansk!

**UPDATE**

Here a small program that demonstrates the issue (with a crude dialog). The wanted behavior is that by clicking on a different value of the radio button, the slider changes range of values, current value and label. What happens instead is that when clicking on "Gradient" the slider stops responding (cannot be dragged anymore), and when clicking on "Gradient" or "Channel" the slider is not updated, in spite of a call to `plt.draw()`

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, RadioButtons

# Set the grid
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1, 2])

# Plot the sliders
axes_slider = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
slider = Slider(axes_slider, 'Channel', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128)

# Plot the radio buttons
axes_button = plt.subplot(grid[1, 0])
button = RadioButtons(axes_button, ('Gradient', 'Channel'), active=1)

plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, right=.9)

def update(_):
    take_gradient = True if button.value_selected == 'Gradient' else False
    if take_gradient:
        slider.valmin = -1
        slider.valmax = 1
        slider.val = 0
        slider.label= 'Gradient'
        slider.valinit = 0
    else:
        slider.valmin = 0
        slider.valmax = 255
        slider.val = 128
        slider.label = 'Channel'
        slider.valinit = 128
    plt.draw()

# Register call-backs with widgets
slider.on_changed(update)
button.on_clicked(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I will try to come up with a short program that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question with a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider itself is a class that hosts and manages some parameters. It does not have a draw method.

That said, it's not enough to only set the parameters of the slider, you would also need to update the axes the slider lives in. At the end this all sums up at doing exactly the steps the slider is doing a initialization, so you can simple call the silder's `__init__` function.

I would strongly recommend to use two different functions, one for changing the slider that is called upon button clicks and one for things that should happen if the slider value is adjusted.

Here is a working example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, RadioButtons

# Set the grid
grid = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1, height_ratios=[1, 2])

# Plot the sliders
axes_slider = plt.subplot(grid[0, 0])
slider = Slider(axes_slider, 'Channel', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128)

# Plot the radio buttons
axes_button = plt.subplot(grid[1, 0])
button = RadioButtons(axes_button, ('Gradient', 'Channel'), active=1)

plt.tight_layout(h_pad=0)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.2, right=.9)

def buttonupdate(val):
    if val == "Gradient":
        axes_slider.clear()
        slider.__init__(axes_slider, 'Gradient', valmin=-1, valmax=1, valinit=0)        
    else:
        axes_slider.clear()
        slider.__init__(axes_slider, 'Channel', valmin=0, valmax=255, valinit=128) 
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()

def sliderupdate(val):
    if slider.label.get_text() == 'Gradient':
        #do something depending on gradient value
        pass
    else:
        #do something depending on channel value
        pass

# Register call-backs with widgets
slider.on_changed(sliderupdate)
button.on_clicked(buttonupdate)

plt.show()
```